# Toogle between hiding and showing a div make me spammer?

Tags: javascript, html

Does the SEO will consider it spam if I use hidden DIV that will be visible on click.

```
<script>
function show(){
document.getElementByd('myDiv').style.display="block";
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="show()"> Software Collection </a>
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">
Content is relevant to my site. But is massive so 
I give user a choice to show when he needs it.
    </div>
```

By doing this will cause SEO problems ? if so, then can I use frames or any other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search engine spider will not care about styles and will find the text. As long as the text is relevant it will not be considered spam.

Try http://www.iwebtool.com/spider_view to see what a search engine will see.

Comment: I've searched that hiding a div will make it spam for Google

Comment: There will be no problem if the hidden content is relevant and can be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some [advice from Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66353) about hidden text and links. They seem to be saying that it won't count against you unless it's a deliberate attempt to add keywords.

For the record, at least some search engine spiders definitely **do** care about styles. For example, if you were to add white text on a white background, your ranking would be penalised.

I expect that, because the approach you're taking is so commonly used with drop-down menus, you'll be okay. It would be difficult for a search engine spider to determine whether or not any content in a div that's initially hidden can ever be visible to the user, so it wouldn't surprise me if such content was disregarded completely (i.e. not indexed, but not treated negatively as an attempt to game the system either).